# Using Indirect function in CountIf formula to count the number of times the text string occurs in a column

Tags: excel, countif, excel-indirect

Hi and thank you in advance for your help.

[image]

I am trying to count the number of times a text string, for example "UML" occurs within a column. The column may contain the text by itself or it may contain the text(UML) in a list with other text(UML,SAS,Excel). I need to be able to count it even if it's within a list. I understand using two * on each side of the text string will work if I write it out but I don't want to write it over and over again.

I am open to alternatives other than countif formula but if there is a way to do it with countif would you please share both.

Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If column F contains your lookup value, and it's contained in square brackets, then building on your formula I'd use:

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$4247,SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE("*" & F2 & "*","[",""),"]",""))
```

We substitute the square brackets for nothing, to remove them on the fly from the lookup value. Then we search the strings, basically for `*UML*`. And this formula is draggable downable (F2 will move with you). Is this what you need?

Comment: Thank you for the help. I will try this! I need F to change with each row as I drag it down. I will try to work that out though. Thanks again!

Comment: No worries... yes, with this formula, 'F2' will update as you drag it down.

Comment: you are right! It worked correctly. Thanks again to everyone.

Comment: Great, I'm glad :-) Don't forget to mark the most appropriate correct answer as 'correct' - we get points and a warm fuzzy feeling.

Answer (score 0):

Just to put my two cents in:

The formula to count column A on what is entered in F2 is:

```
=Countif(A:A,"*" & F2 & "*")
```